# own tracking code on clients side

Tags: php, cookies

I would appreciate bit help with some tracking issues. We have a site which sells a product and on a specific page there is a list of all sellers. When somebody goes to our page by clicking on link there with GET argument (http://example.com?url=example.com) the site is saved into our cookies named sellers and only those sellers which are in the cookie are listed instead of listing all of them.

My quest is if there is any way how to create a tracking code (or something which will better do the job) which we can give to the sellers to put it into their website (as Google Analytics or FB tracking code) to create and store a cookie with this kind of information? This will be used if the client after visiting their store go to our website (not directly, in last 30 days) and only visited stores will be listed?

I would be even happy for some links, I've googled a bit, but probably bad way without result. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What you're doing is right. Normally rather than the URL you'd generate a unique code per seller, and then give them the code to put into the links back to your site, e.g. mywebsite.com?seller=abc123xyz. You then pick up the code, find the seller for that code and store their ID in a cookie for 30 days. Then every time you list out all sellers, check if a valid cookie is there and if so only list that seller.

Comment: I see, I will consider using a code, but there are lot of users who are using our website (adding and deleting list of sellers) so this way it much clearer for them. But I would like to use some inserted JS code at sellers site to achieve the same without clicking on a URL if it's clear. If the client only visits sellers store without clicking anywhere (to our link).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by telling him to just add one transparent blank image tag and give the php file as the src attritube of that image and put sellere tracking code in that file.
like:

```
 <img src="trackSeller.php" />
```

code in trackSeller.php :

```
//Code for fetching seller id and track 
//Trackong code
$img_data = file_get_contents($imgPath);
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo $img_data;
```

Comment: Could you please be bit more explicit, please? Like what should be in first part of your script? I can imagine how to get sellers id from his url, that's ok, but how to save the info into my cookies?

Comment: could you please tell me which sellers are stored in cookie for listing on your page. can you tell me procedure for fetching seller for stroing in cookie so i can give you logic.